# How to change the root path in Nginx configuration

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have created a simple HTML application and I was trying to host it using nginx server.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Simple Test Web App!</title>
</head>

<body >
Test Web App!!!
</body>

</html>
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:latest

# Copy files and directories from the application
COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html

# Tell Docker we are going to use this port
EXPOSE 8080
```

**Docker build**
`docker build -t webapp .`

**Docker run**
`docker run -p 8080:8080 webapp:latest`

**I am able to run the application using http://localhost:8080/ URL**. But I want to know how we can change root path to http://localhost:8080/webapp URL.. Means it should serves the request from **http://localhost:8080/webapp** URI as it was doing with **http://localhost:8080/**

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect your HTML page with subdirectory like HTTP://localhost:8080/webapp instead of HTTP://localhost:8080,
for that, you need to create nginx configuration file that redirect your HTML page into your subdirectory URL. in your nginx configuration file you should add following line,

`location /htmlsite { root /var/www/htmlsite; try_files $uri $uri/ =404; }`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have added the change that you have suggested but it is giving a 404 error.  while hitting http://localhost:8080/webapp